# Creating a static lib while the header includes another .h from another static lib

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-linking

I apologize if the question is confusing, but I will try to explain it as best I can.

I am creating a GLFW/GLEW wrapper which will be a foundation in another project where I build on top of that.

The header of the file in the static library has

```
#include <GL/glew.h
#include <GLFW/glfw.h
...
```

which are both using a static library inside of my project.

What I would like to know is if I create a static library from my wrapper (wrapper.lib), will I still need to include GLEW and GLFW's .lib and .h files in order to use my wrapper in another project?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are confused between compiling and linking.  The compiler needs whatever header files declare the functions you want to call.  The linker needs whatever libraries contain the bodies of those functions.

Comment: generally static libraries only have your own code in them, you can combine multiple static libraries into a single library though

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I had an issue when I created the .lib, I created a dummy project, setup my .lib and .h file in that project and when I compiled my code (I am using scons to make cross plat easier) I got an error in the included .h file where it could not find GL/glew.h

Comment: Can we assume a cross plat is an angry platypus?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you only need to add the .h files to your new project. The created static library will encompass any static libraries that were used to create it.

Thank you for coming to my Ted Talk